# Compare value in a key value list in AngularJS and print that value in my view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this key, value list in my controller:

```
$scope.events = [
  {eventID: 3200, eventName: "HO BASE PRICE CHG"},
  {eventID: 1600, eventName: "DAMAGED M/D TO 0"}
];
```

and I want to compare my eventID with one value coming
from a web service in a field called EVENT_ID and if there's a match then print the eventName in my html table where it says "**{{EVENT NAME ACCORDING TO EVENT ID}}**".

The EVENT_ID field is in my ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in (exportDataEventDesc.result.slice(0, exportDataEventDesc.result.length-7))">

   <td style="text-align: left">{{EVENT NAME ACCORDING TO EVENT ID}}</td>

      <td ng-bind = "+ '$' +(d.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW | number : 2)"></td>
      <td ng-bind="d.merchMetrics.SALES_LW_CHG_LY + '%'"></td>
      <td ng-bind="d.merchMetrics.SALES_L4W_CHG_LY + '%'" ></td>
      <td ng-bind="d.merchMetrics.SALES_L13W_CHG_LY + '%'"></td>
      <td ng-bind="d.merchMetrics.SALES_L52W_CHG_LY + '%'"></td>
</tr>
```

Also one more questions, is there something like a "map" in JavaScript?

or which is the best way to achieve what I want, the way I'm doing it is OK? or there's a better one?

WS Response:
[image: WS Response]

Controller:
[image: Controller]

Comment: Check these functions

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
and also 
[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and for your time, I'll check it!  =)

Comment: You could also show your controller code and server response to get a detailed answer

Comment: You can use lodash for mapping, filtering, searching objects, etc. https://lodash.com/docs

Comment: @EvansDianga

I add some screenshots ;)

Comment: @Holle

Great, thanks for your time =)